# Пытаюсь добавить кнопку копировать в Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Программа генерирует пароль. Нужна кнопка рядом с сгенерированным паролем "Копировать", после нажатия которой пароль копируется в буфер обмена.

Кнопку добавил, добавил скрипт JS в отдельный файл main.js (как он работает я не понимаю, я по питону больше). Скрипт лежит в папке static. Django 4. Python 3.10

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'password_generator_project/static/',]
```

password.html (тут сгенерированный пароль)

```
{% load static %}
<head>
<script src="{% static '/main.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<div class="container text-center">
<br>
    <h1>Your password is:</h1>
    <br>
    <h2 class="alert alert-success">{{ password }}</h2>
    <br>
    <button id="copy-button" class="btn btn-primary">Copy</button>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-warning">Home</a>
<div>
```

**main.js**

```
console.log('JavaScript code loaded');

const copyButton = document.getElementById('copy-button');
const passwordField = document.querySelector('.alert-success');
copyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(passwordField.textContent);
  copyButton.textContent = 'Copied!';
  setTimeout(() => {
    copyButton.textContent = 'Copy';
  }, 2000);
});
```

При нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит. Пробовал в разных браузерах.

Понимаю что просто не выполняется скрипт, но визуально вроде все подключено и прописано, ошибок никаких нет. При нажатии кнопки консоль JS в хроме ничего не дает.

Answer (score 0):

Копирование в БО таким способом - асинхронное действо.

Вот работающий пример

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText('Превед, медвед!')
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Получилось!');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Ошибка копирования', err);
    });
})
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Тест</button>
```

Более подробно в этой статье
https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/358494/

Comment: Не получается никак. Пробовал и как вы указали и по ссылке

Comment: @Alex, нужно показывать свои примеры. Это можно сделать отредактировав свой вопрос. Т.е. прямо в вопросе показать еще один свой вариант решения.

Answer (score 0):

Решил по другому, без создания отдельного файла со скриптом
Прописал скрип с функцией прямо в html файле и вызвал onclick кнопкой

```
<script>
    function copyToClipboard() {
        const passwordText = document.querySelector('.alert.alert-success').innerText;
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(passwordText)
            .then(() => {
                alert(`Получилось!`);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Ошибка копирования', err);
            });
    }
</script>
```

Правда теперь браузер почему-то просит подтвердить действие в всплывающем окне, но это видимо, особенность хрома

Comment: Так у Вас `alert` в случае успеха прописан.

Comment: Просто убрать этот блок?
.then(() => {
                alert(`Получилось!`);
            })

Comment: Да, уберите его